# Pandas: Check if a value exist in a column, create a new column, exist add 1 if not add 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame

```
df = columnA=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
     columnB=['Apple AA','Banana BB',NaN,'Strawberry DD',NaN,'Blueberry EE']
```

I want to create a new column if columnB contains values

```
df = columnA=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
     columnB=['Apple AA','Banana BB',NaN,'Strawberry DD',NaN,'Blueberry EE']
     columnC=[1,1,0,1,0,1]
```

My code:

```
df[columnC] = df[columnB].map(lambda x: 1 if len(x) > 0 else 0 if len(x) == 0)
```

Or

```
columnC = np.repeat(0, df.shape[0]
for i in df:
   if len(df[columnB]) > 0:
      df[columnC] = 1
```

Neither are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.notnull()` to test if your values are not NaN

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'columnB':['Apple AA','Banana BB',np.NaN,'Strawberry DD',np.NaN,'Blueberry EE']})

df['columnC'] = df['columnB'].notnull()*1
```

The multiplication by 1 is used to convert booleans to binary values.
Also be careful not to forget quotes around your column names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'B': ['Apple', 'Ba', np.nan, 'St', np.nan, 'e']})

df['C'] = df['B'].isna()

 A      B      C
0  1  Apple  False
1  2     Ba  False
2  3    NaN   True
3  4     St  False
4  5    NaN   True
5  6      e  False
```

Then convert the boolean value to 0 1

```
df['C'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: 1 if not x else 0)


   A      B  C
0  1  Apple  1
1  2     Ba  1
2  3    NaN  0
3  4     St  1
4  5    NaN  0
5  6      e  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, using `np.where` from numpy.

```
df['C']=np.where(df['B'].notnull(),1,0)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
        A           B       C
1   Apple           AA      1
2   Banana          BB      1
3   NaN             None    0
4   Strawberry      DD      1
5   NaN             None    0
6   Blueberry       EE      1
```